# RxJS: catchError returns union type

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I mean, `catchError` returns an `Observable` union type: `Observable<{} | Page}` instead of `Observable<Page>`.

I'm getting this compiler message:

```
Type 'Observable<{} | Page>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Page>'.
  Type '{} | Page' is not assignable to type 'Page'.
    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Page': total, audits
```

Related code is:

```
public searchFromStorageByCriteria(filter: Query): Observable<Page> {
    const buildPage = () => map((response: Response) => this.buildPage(response));
    const onErrorEmptyPage = () => catchError(() => Observable.of(Page.EMPTY));

    let url:string = this.buildURL(user, app, filter);
    return this.authHttp.get(url)
        .pipe(
            buildPage(),
            onErrorEmptyPage()
        );
}
```

The problem is located on `catchError` since:

```
export declare function catchError<T, R>(selector: (err: any, caught: Observable<T>) => ObservableInput<R>): OperatorFunction<T, T | R>;
```

As you can see it's returning an `: OperatorFunction<T, T | R>` and also `caught: Observable<T>`.

`Page.EMPTY` is:

```
export class Page {
    readonly total: number;
    readonly audits: Array<Audit>;

    public static EMPTY:Page = {total: 0, audits: []};
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should use like this, Observable.of<Page>(Page.EMPTY);

Answer (score 1):

The solution is about overriding `catchError` signature:

```
catchError<Page, never>
```

Take a look on [never type](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/never.html).